# Cloudflare sessions

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I wanted to add a feature to my site similar to this:

When a new session starts look at the utm_source/utm_medium querystring values and also the referrer. Based on that display a differnt phone number of the site, so for example google cpc, bing cpc, google organic, bing organic would have different numbers.

The number of calls to each number should then give an indication of which traffic source generated the calls.

The problem is, because we're using clouldflare, if a user is served a page from the cache then there is no session_start event on the origin server.

Is there a solution to get around this? Is there anyway to do this on cloudflare itself, perhaps using its "workers"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare workers can be used to accomplish that. The worker script will first need to determine which phone number to show. This can be done by checking the query params or a cookie or any other aspect of the request. Then the worker script can take the original response body (from the cache or the origin server) and replace all occurences of the original phone number with the new phone number.

Here's an example worker script that does that. To determine which phone number to show, it will first check the query parameters, as you mentioned. When it sees the `utm_source` query param, it will also set a cookie that can then be checked in all subsequent requests to show the same phone number.

```js
// The name of the cookie that will be used to determine which phone number to show
const cookieName = "phone_num_id";

// The list of all phone numbers to use
const phoneNumbers = [
  {
    id: "google-cpc",
    utmSource: "google",
    utmMedium: "cpc",
    phoneNumber: "222-222-2222"
  },
  {
    id: "bing-cpc",
    utmSource: "bing",
    utmMedium: "cpc",
    phoneNumber: "333-333-3333"
  }
];

// This adds a "fetch" event listener which will be called for all incoming requests
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
  // Forward the incoming request and get the original response. If Cloudflare has already cached
  // this request, this will return the cached response, otherwise it will make the request to
  // the origin
  let response = await fetch(request);

  // Check the content type of the response and fallback to an empty string
  // if there is no content-type header
  let contentType = response.headers.get("content-type") || "";

  // We're only interested in changing respones that have a content-type starting
  // with "text/html". Anything else will be returned without any modifications
  if (/^text\/html/.test(contentType)) {
    // `newPhoneNumberData` will be the new phone number to show (if any)
    let newPhoneNumberData;

    // searchParams are the query parameters for this request
    let searchParams = new URL(request.url).searchParams;

    // If the request has a `utm_source` query param, use that to determine which phone number to show
    if (searchParams.has("utm_source")) {
      let utmSource = searchParams.get("utm_source") || "";
      let utmMedium = searchParams.get("utm_medium") || "";
      // Lookup the phone number based on the `utmSource` and `utmMedium`
      newPhoneNumberData = phoneNumbers.find(
        phoneNumber =>
          phoneNumber.utmSource === utmSource &&
          phoneNumber.utmMedium === utmMedium
      );

      // If we found a match, set a cookie so that subsequent requests get the same phone number
      if (newPhoneNumberData) {
        // In order to modify the response headers, we first have to duplicate the response
        // so that it becomes mutable
        response = new Response(response.body, response);

        // Now set a cookie with the id of the new phone number to use. You should modify the properties
        // of the cookie for your use case. See this page for more information:
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
        response.headers.append(
          "Set-Cookie",
          `${cookieName}=${newPhoneNumberData.id}; Max-Age=2147483647`
        );
      }
    }

    // If we weren't able to determine the new phone number based on the query params, try
    // checking the cookies next
    if (!newPhoneNumberData) {
      let cookieHeader = request.headers.get("cookie") || "";

      // split each of the cookies and remove leading/trailing whitespace
      let cookies = cookieHeader.split(";").map(str => str.trim());

      // Find the phone number cookie
      let phoneNumberCookieString = cookies.find(cookieString =>
        cookieString.startsWith(`${cookieName}=`)
      );

      // If the request has the phone number cookie, use that
      if (phoneNumberCookieString) {
        // Extract the phone number id from the cookie
        const phoneNumberId = phoneNumberCookieString.split("=")[1];

        // Lookup the phone number data based on the ID
        newPhoneNumberData = phoneNumbers.find(
          phoneNumber => phoneNumber.id === phoneNumberId
        );
      }
    }

    // If we found a matching phone number to use, now we'll need to replace all occurences
    // of the original phone number with the new one before returning the response
    if (newPhoneNumberData) {
      // Get the original response body
      let responseBody = await response.text();

      // Use a regex with the `g` flag to find/replace all occurences of the original phone number.
      // This would look for a phone number like "(111)-111-1111" but you can modify this to fit
      // however your original phone number appears
      responseBody = responseBody.replace(
        /\(?111\)?[-\s]*111[-\s]*1111/g,
        newPhoneNumberData.phoneNumber
      );

      // Create a new response with the updated responseBody. We also pass the original `response` as the
      // second argument in order to copy all other properties from the original response (status, headers, etc)
      response = new Response(responseBody, response);
    }
  }

  return response;
}
```